# How can I get my react app in cloud storage and app engine api to be under the same domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I have recently moved to GCP for cloud hosting. I have a react app hosted in cloud storage and a Go REST api hosted on app engine. I am trying to figure out how I can use the same domain name for both of these.

For example:

```
www.mydomain.com/
www.mydomain.com/api/v1/*
```

Coming from an AWS background, it would be something like this:

[image]

I have tried searching many hours for a solution, but have no luck solving this. Any advice / help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think its possible to have one domain pointing to two different origins. why don't you have "api.mydomain.com" pointing to your backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https). You can set up a [URL map](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#url_maps) to match the desired paths, and point different requests to the [backend bucket](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets) and [app engine](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless), respectively.

For HTTPS load balancing, the target HTTPS proxy uses SSL certificates. It uses a URL map to make a routing. Based on the routing, the proxy forwards requests to specific backend services or backend buckets. The URL map can specify additional actions, such as pointing to a NEG (network endpoint group- that specifies a group of backend endpoints for a load balancer) which in turn points to a Cloud Run, App Engine, or Cloud Functions service.

We are using the same concept to point the load balancer with the help of a URL map to backend Cloud Storage buckets where you have the React App and to a NEG service, a REST Golang API hosted on App Engine.

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for.