# Google Cloud App Engine (Django) and Google Cloud Storage working on a Single Domain with Custom URLs

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a Django application working on supereye.co.uk.

Django handles all URL routing such as supereye.co.uk/signin supereye.co.uk/watch etc.

I am also using Google Cloud Storage that is working with Google Cloud App Engine on gs://production2.supereye.co.uk

How shall I handle the routing so both App Engine and Storage can be accessible through the supereye.co.uk domain. For instance :

```
supereye.co.uk      -> Django App, Google Cloud App Engine
data.supereye.co.uk -> Google Cloud Storage bucket, gs://production2.supereye.co.uk
```

Is there any way to achieve this without relating Django App to bucket at all ?

Can the bucket be accessible by its own resources while using a proper https custom domail such as "https://data.supereye.co.uk" rather than for instance "https://storage.googleapis.com/production-supereye-co-uk/video/DFeMfXUk4Te/thumbnail/Mx73lhda8n8x.webp" ?

Is there any internal Google Cloud tool that will let me achieve this ?

Comment: Hi @SuperEye, if you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark on the left side under the vote arrows and upvoting it. I'd really appreciate it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002053/15774177), you can do this using a load balancer. You can set up a URL map to match the desired paths, and point different requests to the backend bucket and app engine, respectively.

If you just wanna name your bucket with a domain name then I suggest you go through [Domain-named bucket verification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification). This link focuses mainly on requirements for creating buckets with domain names.